# Ошибка в phpMyAdmin: Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Почему в phpmyadmin при входе выдает ошибку `#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`. Установку выполнял следующим образом:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Пароль назначил. OC Linux mint. Пробовал ввести в консоли `mysql -u root -p` После потребовало ввести и снова выдало ошибку `#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: че это taskset зачем

Comment: @АнтонВеселов - Утилита командной строки tasksel позволяет с помощью системы меню выбрать одну или несколько групп пакетов и установить их в свою Ubuntu систему.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ошибка `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` означает, что у пользователя root с указываемым вами паролем нет прав доступа к СУБД.

Видимо пароль не установился или установился не верно, либо вместо 'root'@'localhost' был установлен пользователь 'root'@127.0.0.1. Попробуйте в консоли набрать

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

Если после этого вас пустит в СУБД, необходимо создать дополнительного пользователя 'root'@'localhost'

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
WITH GRANT OPTION
IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

Если не пускает, значит, нужно восстанавливать пароль для root. Найдите конфигурационный файл my.cnf и добавьте в секцию [mysqld] директиву `skip-grant-tables`, которая отключит проверку прав доступа

```
[mysqld]
...
skip-grant-tables
```

После чего перезагрузите сервер. Теперь вы можете входить MySQL без пароля, войдите и переустановите пароль

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

После этого следует убрать директиву `skip-grant-tables` из my.cnf и перезапустить сервер.

Comment: Так же стоит напомнить что скип грант тэйбел надо закоментировать после установки нового пароля.

Comment: @Naumov, спасибо, дополнил ответ.

Comment: SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root')
Ответ MySQL: Документация

#1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Comment: Где искать конфигурационный файл my.cnf в Ubuntu?

Comment: Можно ориентироваться на таблицу 4.2 по ссылке https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html MySQL будет последовательно опрашивать папки в том порядке, в котором они указаны в таблице. Будет использован тот файл, который будет найден первым.

Answer (score 2):

в новых версиях после MySQL 5.7.6 команда изменения пароля несколько отличается:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно ввести:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

и ответить на вопросы
далее логинимся:

```
sudo mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```