# После установки LAMP-а и при заходе в phpmyadmin выдает ошибку (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lamp

```
#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

До этих пор (18.10.2016 (16.48 по Киеву) ни один из указных способов на этом сайте мою проблему не решают. 
Если я делаю так: `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` то получаю `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Возможно проблема в этом : 
  Файл `«20auto-upgrades.ucf-old»` в каталоге `«/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/»` игнорируется, так как он не имеет неправильное расширение.

Такая проблема возникала при установке. Я её проигнорировал :)

Comment: Зайдите в mysql из консоли и покажите результат запроса `use mysql; select Host from user where User="root";`

Comment: @Pink Tux эти команды не подходят для терминала. Я пользуюсь УБУНТУ а не ВИНДОВС

Comment: Э... Всем подходят, а вам нет? Странно. И при чём тут Windows - непонятненько.

Comment: @Pink Tux значит я что то не понимаю ... Опишите пожалуйста  что мне нужно сделать детальней.

Comment: @Pink Tux Это мне не подходит. Когда я так делаю так как там написано у меня выдаёт ошибку **  ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' ' **

Comment: Может с паролем что-то не так?

Comment: @Metod, PinkTux вообще-то написал команды, которые надо вводить внутри mysql консоли. К ОС которая обслуживает БД эти комманды не имеют никакого отношения.

Comment: @Metod,   *Когда я так делаю так как там написано* -- там НЕ написано заходить в mysql под юзером `root@localhost`. Вы читали что-то не то, видимо. Прочитайте ещё раз ответ на вопрос, и будьте повнимательней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Две первые причины, которые могут вызывать эту ошибку:

1. С точки зрения mysql `127.0.0.1` и `localhost` - это разные вещи. И если у вас настроен доступ для пользователя `root` с хоста `127.0.0.1`, то это не значит, что доступ у него будет и с `localhost`.
2. Банально ошибка в рутовом пароле.

Что делать в этих случаях подробно рассмотрено в [ответе на вопрос #552936](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552936/). Сделайте всё что там описано, если не поможет - дополните свой вопрос результатами этих действий, будем думать дальше.

Comment: Похоже, судя по руководству, первое ваше утверждение не во всех случаях истинно: `An attempt to connect to the host 127.0.0.1 normally resolves to the localhost account. However, this fails if the server is run with the --skip-name-resolve option, so the 127.0.0.1 account is useful in that case.`. Это упоминается для версий 5.5 и 5.6, для 5.7 этого примечания уже нет, но оно указано в самом описании опции.

Comment: @MAH69K, версия в вопросе не указана, а судя по ошибке всё может быть. Но на то к программисту голова и прилагается, чтобы ей думать в разные стороны ;)

Comment: @Pink Tux если я делаю так:

Comment: @Pink Tux   `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` то получаю `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: @Pink Tux а если `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin`  то веравно получаю ошибку `#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: @Metod: вы принципиально что-ли не читаете что вам пишут? Вам же ещё в самом начале дали ссылку на аналогичный вопрос, где есть волшебные слова "Если не пускает, значит,...".